# Send post data through symfony without a form?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Let's say I had a link like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('cart?item_id='.$cart->getItemId().'&a=b') ?>">Cart</a>
```

Is it possible to change it so instead of `a` being a query parameter it was sent through via POST instead so that it wouldn't be in the URL of the page? Same data, just not visible in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Using `url_for`, it's not possible. You have to use [`link_to`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/UrlHelper#method_link_to) and give the option `post => true` to emulate a POST as a link:

> - 'post' - if set to true, the link submits a POST request instead of GET (caution: do not use inside a form)

Instead of:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('cart?item_id='.$cart->getItemId().'&a=b') ?>">Cart</a>
```

You should write:

```
<?php echo link_to(
  'Cart',
  'cart?item_id='.$cart->getItemId().'&a=b',
  array('post' => true)
) ?>
```

Which will generate, something really ugly, but that will send a POST request instead of a GET:

`<a onclick="var f = document.createElement('form'); f.style.display = 'none'; this.parentNode.appendChild(f); f.method = 'post'; f.action = this.href;var m = document.createElement('input'); m.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); m.setAttribute('name', '_csrf_token'); m.setAttribute('value', 'd9dbcba8c82084819006af93fbf8f961'); f.appendChild(m);f.submit();return false;" href="/cart/item_id/21/a/b">Cart</a>`

By the way, as the doc says, DO NOT USE this inside a form..

Answer (score 0):

You should use a form to achieve what you want. Something like this:

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="cart?item_id=ITEM_ID">
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="b" />
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();">Cart</a>
    <button type="submit">Cart</button>
</form>
```

If you want to use an `<a>` element you will need Javascript to submit the form. But you can also use a `button` element, which you can style exactly the same as an `<a>` with CSS. Both options are shown in the code example.

**Edit:**
I completely missed the fact that your question was related to Symfony, but this method may still apply. But j0k's answer shows how to do this with Symfony specific code.